# How can I rank and grade based on average marks

Tags: sql, mariadb

[

```
SELECT r.AdNo,
       r.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.SubjectID = 101 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS ENGLISH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.SubjectID = 102 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS KISWAHILI,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.SubjectID = 103 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS MATH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.SubjectID = 104 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS CRE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.SubjectID = 105 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS 'SOCIAL STUDIES',
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.SubjectID THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL',
       (sum(s.score)/count(s.SubjectID) ) AS 'AVERAGE',
       g.grade_letter
  FROM student r
       INNER JOIN marks s ON r.AdNo = s.AdNo
       INNER JOIN subject p ON s.SubjectID = p.SubjectID
       INNER JOIN grades g ON 77.2 BETWEEN g.lowerlimit AND g.upperlimit
  GROUP BY r.Name
  order by AVERAGE DESC;
```

]

```
[SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for category
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CategoryID` (`CategoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for grades
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grades`;
CREATE TABLE `grades` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grade_letter` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lowerlimit` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `upperlimit` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `grade_letter` (`grade_letter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for marks
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `marks`;
CREATE TABLE `marks` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AdNo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubjectID` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `AdNo` (`AdNo`,`SubjectID`,`CategoryID`),
  KEY `SubjectID` (`SubjectID`),
  KEY `CategoryID` (`CategoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `marks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AdNo`) REFERENCES `student` (`AdNo`),
  CONSTRAINT `marks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SubjectID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`SubjectID`),
  CONSTRAINT `marks_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `category` (`CategoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for student
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdNo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `AdNo` (`AdNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for subject
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subject`;
CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SubjectID` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubjectName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SubjectID` (`SubjectID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;]
```

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. The Google Drive link is not suitable.

Comment: I can't post database model image..

Comment: It would be best if you provided the output you're getting and the output you're trying to get given some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Rather make the upper limit of A- the same as the lower limit of A, etc.
Also, your grades table doesn't account for a student having an average mark of less than 1. In that case my query will return "???" for the grade.

```
SELECT m.*, COALESCE(grades.grade_letter, '???') AS GRADE
FROM (
    SELECT student.AdNo, student.Name,
           SUM(IF(subject.SubjectID = 101, marks.score, 0)) AS ENGLISH,
           SUM(IF(subject.SubjectID = 102, marks.score, 0)) AS KISWAHILI,
           SUM(IF(subject.SubjectID = 103, marks.score, 0)) AS MATH,
           SUM(IF(subject.SubjectID = 104, marks.score, 0)) AS CRE,
           SUM(IF(subject.SubjectID = 105, marks.score, 0)) AS "SOCIAL STUDIES",
           SUM(IF(subject.SubjectID IS NOT NULL, marks.score, 0)) AS TOTAL,
           SUM(marks.score)/COUNT(*) AS AVERAGE
    FROM student
    INNER JOIN marks ON student.AdNo = marks.AdNo
    INNER JOIN subject ON marks.SubjectID = subject.SubjectID
    GROUP BY student.AdNo
) AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN grades
    ON m.AVERAGE >= grades.lowerlimit
    AND m.AVERAGE < grades.upperlimit
ORDER BY m.AVERAGE DESC;
```

Adding another student with 0 marks for all subjects gives this:

```
+--------+------+---------+-----------+------+------+----------------+-------+---------+-------+
| AdNo   | Name | ENGLISH | KISWAHILI | MATH | CRE  | SOCIAL STUDIES | TOTAL | AVERAGE | GRADE |
+--------+------+---------+-----------+------+------+----------------+-------+---------+-------+
| TU-003 | D K  |      67 |        80 |   90 |   70 |             79 |   386 |    77.2 | A-    |
| TU-004 | G K  |      57 |        76 |   61 |   78 |             80 |   352 |    70.4 | B+    |
| TU-001 | G C  |      67 |        68 |   78 |   54 |             76 |   343 |    68.6 | B+    |
| TU-002 | F K  |      60 |        34 |   74 |   50 |             67 |   285 |      57 | B-    |
| TU-005 | X X  |       0 |         0 |    0 |    0 |              0 |     0 |       0 | ???   |
+--------+------+---------+-----------+------+------+----------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I rank student using the average marks? Example DK Rank 1. GK Rank 2. then both GC and FK  Rank: 3 so the next student should be rank: 5. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Ah, I did not understand that from your question. That's why you should provide an example or two of what you want to achieve in your question. Do you mean that students with identical average marks will have the same rank? Or students with the same grade letter? Perhaps you should update the question.

Comment: I meant student with the identical average marks will have same rank

Comment: OK, I see. I'm not sure how to do that with just SQL. It would be very easy with whatever programming language you are using to execute the SQL statements and process the results, though. I suggest you update your question to include the sample data showing two students with the same average and showing what output you're looking for. Then remove the "accepted" check mark from my answer (you can click the up arrow instead if you like) so that other people know that this question is still open.